# On the sum of relatively prime number $<N$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, asymptotics

Let $A(N)$ be a function which is the sum of all numbers relatively prime and $<N$ and $B(N)$ the sum of remaining $N−\phi(N)$ numbers.
Then I have the following questions-

**Q-1** For what values of $N$ , $A(N) >B(N)$ ? And for what is $A(N)<B(N)$?

**Q-2** What are the asymptotics of the  function $A(N)$ and $B(N)$?

---

I have tried working by observing 
$A(N)= N \phi(N)/2$ and  $B(N)=\frac{N(N-1)-N \phi(N)}{2}$ but in Vain. And I have no hint for the asymptotics

Comment: Do you have the first few terms off hand? You could check OEIS.org

Comment: http://oeis.org/A023896

Comment: @Alan Thanks for the reference . But what I want is all values of $N$ does those inequity work . Not the partial value (easy to show that for $N=3^n$ we have $A(N)>B(N)$  and for $N=2^n$ its opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $A(N)<B(N)$ is equivalent to $$\phi(N)<{N-1\over2}$$ Also, $$\phi(N)=N\prod_{p\mid N}(1-p^{-1})$$ so $A(N)<B(N)$ is equivalent to $$\prod_{p\mid N}(1-p^{-1})<{1\over2}-{1\over2N}$$ So it's mostly a question of whether there are enough small prime divisors of $N$ to bring that product down below $1/2$.

Comment: From this analysis, we see that $A(N)<B(N)$ for all even $N$ except powers of $2$. Odd $N$ aren't as easy to characterize. The smallest odd $N$ for which $A(N)<B(N)$ is $N=105$.

Comment: @GregMartin which code did you use to get to $N=105$?

Comment: I suspect the only code Greg used was the genetic code in his DNA. Look; you want a lot of small primes. The prime 3 all by itself isn't enough: $1-(1/3)>1/2$. 3 and 5? No, $(2/3)(4/5)>1/2$. How about 3, 5, and 7? $(2/3)(4/5)(6/7)<1/2$; bingo!

Comment: @GerryMyerson +1 ..completely impressed by DNA anology

Comment: It's nice to have it insinuated that my ribosomes know the sieve of Eratosthenes :) but @ShivamPatel: any code that knows how to compute the Euler phi function can quickly test your inequality.